# NoClassDefFoundError after migrating to Android API 28

Tags: android, proguard, kotlin-android-extensions, android-9.0-pie

I know, similar questions have been asked, but I think, my situation is different. Please don't delete.

I've started getting NoClassDefFoundError error after migrating to API 28, just like many other folks. I've seen others experienced this issue because Google has deprecated org.apache classes, which required changing manifest, but I don't use apache classes in my project.

What makes investigation difficult is that there is no custom classes in the stack trace below, and it's not even clear what class was not found. The worst part of it is that I can't reproduce the bug in an emulator, or on a real device, and could see it only in Google Play Store reports, which showed that all crashes have happened on Android 9 devices.

I've two questions about it:

- Does the fact that there is no custom classes in stack trace mean that that's an internal Google problem and I can't really fix it?
- How can I change my project to get more information, e.g. to see what class was not found?

On unrelated note, I think, maintaining newer Android's versions become very difficult and their support simply doesn't exist, so stackoverflow is my last hope.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at com.google.android.a.a.m.d (m.java:266)
  at com.google.android.a.a.m.a (m.java:113)
  at com.google.android.a.a.g.a (g.java:206)
  at com.google.android.a.a.g.a (g.java:166)
  at com.google.android.a.a.e$a$2.run (e.java:242)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at com.google.android.a.a.m.d (m.java:266)
  at com.google.android.a.a.m.a (m.java:113)
  at com.google.android.a.a.g.a (g.java:206)
  at com.google.android.a.a.g.a (g.java:166)
  at com.google.android.a.a.e$a$2.run (e.java:242)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run (HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Below are also all dependencies that I use in this project:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/accessory-v2.5.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/sdk-v1.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/lvl.aar')

}
```

It's a Kotlin project, and Kotlin version is 1.3.10

**Update:**
Recompiled the same code with API 27, posted the app to Play Store again, and didn't see any crashes since then, so it's definitely specific to API 28.

Comment: de-obfuscate the stack-trace first... else it could be just any class.

Comment: @martin - I will, but that all andoid's classes. How can I find a class that "was not found"? Will de-obfuscation of android classes help with that?

Comment: are you using any google map related  things?

Comment: @notTdar - no, don't use google map at all.

Comment: @OlegGryb alright, any other google related services?

Comment: "Does the fact that there is no custom classes in stack trace mean that that's an internal Google problem and I can't really fix it?" -- possibly. It seems to be a from a Play Services library. Make sure that you are on the current versions of those. "but that all andoid's classes" -- no, `com.google.android` is usually from Play Services.

Comment: @notTdar - added all dependencies to the post. Camera and Samsung's accessory protocol libs are probably not very common.

Comment: @CommonsWare - anything I can do to improve the output and get more details? If it's a proguard issue, I need to know what class names I need to "keep". I've already added keep for com.google.android** , but all of that is "fishing", not fixing...

Comment: @OlegGryb, can you update the google play services dependencies above.

Comment: Normally, a `NoClassDefFoundError` will say what was not found. I do not know why it is not doing that in this case. But since your Play Services libraries are 1-2 major versions behind, I'd start there. If you cannot reproduce this consistently, then start collecting information about what devices are reporting the problem, and see if you can identify some patterns.

Comment: @CommonsWare and notTdar, I'm panicky afraid upgrading play services due backward incompatibility, but if it's the only suggestion, I'll do that in beta. All crashes happened on Android 9 devices. Since Google was changing permission model to improve privacy, it could be related to that.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can different play services libs have different versions? I believe, I read somewhere that they all should be the same. Some play libs allows ver 17+, while others - only 16+. Should I use the smallest, but the same version for all libs?

Comment: I have not kept up to date with the current recommendations for Play Services versions, and I have not used about half of the Play Services libraries that are in your `dependencies` list. So I do not know what Google would suggest here, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

The mystery is solved. After all, it was related to org.apache classes and I'm sure, it will create a hidden problem for many folks migrating to API 28.

While my project doesn't have any dependency on Apache classes, Google own API (licensing library in my case) does have such a dependency.

So, even if you don't use Apache in your project directly, you never know what's in dependencies and that's why you should always have the below line in your manifest's application tag when deal with API 28:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Lastly, since Google Play Store did lousy job in providing a meaningful stack trace, I had to inject [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) code to the app's beta code and to ask users to send a crash report to me. Fortunately, I had one user who has agreed to help with this. Below is what I've got through email.

My opinion about quality of Android platform gets worse with every new version they release.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils;
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy.decodeExtras(ServerManagedPolicy.java:3)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy.processServerResponse(ServerManagedPolicy.java:3)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator.handleResponse(LicenseValidator.java:1)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator.verify(LicenseValidator.java:37)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker$ResultListener$2.run(LicenseChecker.java:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.gryb.gacw-buYW6A5hesJP-wfcU6nnVg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/info.gryb.gacw-buYW6A5hesJP-wfcU6nnVg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 9 more
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/info.gryb.gacw-buYW6A5hesJP-wfcU6nnVg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/info.gryb.gacw-buYW6A5hesJP-wfcU6nnVg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy.decodeExtras(ServerManagedPolicy.java:3)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy.processServerResponse(ServerManagedPolicy.java:3)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator.handleResponse(LicenseValidator.java:1)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseValidator.verify(LicenseValidator.java:37)
at com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker$ResultListener$2.run(LicenseChecker.java:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Comment: @Bugs Happen LOL, I wish we didn't need to be heroic to do simple things in Android :)

Comment: Some dreams are just too beautiful to be true 

Comment: Isn't possible to replace the deprecated HttpClient in the Google's licensing sample with something else?

Comment: @Oldes Everything is possible, but I don't want to touch old lib that works and doesn't belong to me.

Comment: This did not resolve my problem. I still had to add something to run unit tests. `testRuntimeOnly 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12'`

Comment: Wow, people are still using ACRA in 2021? Haven't used that in 10 years....